# How to add more than one cast for a movie model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a movie app in Django. I have a model named `Movie` with its usual properties. I want to create another model named Cast where I'll create different actors. For a given movie, I want to be able to link different actors and also the actors shouldn't be removed when a movie is deleted. I tried using ForeignKey for the Cast at the actors field in Movie model. Thus it looked like this:

```
class MovieCast(models.Model):
    """
    Model for the actors in a movie
    """
    actor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Movie(models.Model):
    """
    Base class for the properties our movie will have
    """
    **other items**
    cast = models.ForeignKey(MovieCast, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

What the problem is that the models do show up in admin site and I am able to add an actor to the `MovieCast` model, but in the `cast` field of the `Movie` model, I can't add more than one actors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You work with a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) to represent relations where a movie can have multiple `MovieCast`s and a `MovieCast` can belong to multiple `Movie`s.

For example:

```
class MovieCast(models.Model):
    actor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    cast = models.ManyToManyField(
        MovieCast,
        related_name='movies'
    )
```

We can then construct for example two movies and two `MovieCast` objects:

```
titanic = Movie.objects.create(name='Titanic')
laborday = Movie.objects.create(name='Labor Day')

leonardo = MovieCast.objects.create(actor_name='Leonardo DiCaprio')
kate = MovieCast.objects.create(actor_name='Kate Winslet')

titanic.cast.add(leonardo, kate)
laborday.cast.add(kate)
```

For more information, see the [*many-to-many relationships* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: What's the 'related_name' for?

Comment: @pratik: the name of the relation in reverse, so to access in what movies a `MovieCast` played.